# Retrieving data based on current date and time in perl

Tags: sql, perl

Data in my database:

```
loadtime             |    location
-------------------------------------
2000-May-08 10:45am  |    switzerland
2014-may-22 11:00am  |    canada
2014-may-22 10:40am  |    canada
```

I just want to display the data which has the latest/current loadtime like 30mins just passed:

```
my $sqlstmt="SELECT loadtime from mydata
             WHERE loadtime =sysdate -30/1440";
```

I want to display only the new inserted data. Hence, if there's no new inserted data yet it will send email notification. But i dont know how to implement this?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: So you want to display records that are newer that 30 minutes and haven't been displayed before?

Comment: Just keep track of the date of the latest record displayed, and show everything that is later than that *and* newer than 30 minutes.

Comment: @Pradeep: Im using oracle as my rdbms

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the date of the latest record displayed, and show everything that is later than that and newer than 30 minutes.

Something like this should do what you need. Note that it's untested, except that it does compile.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my ($dsn, $user, $pass) = ();

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass) or die $DBI::errstr;

my ($latest) = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT sysdate - 0.5/24');

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(<<__END_SQL__);
SELECT loadtime, location
FROM table
WHERE (sysdate - loadtime) * 24 < 0.5
AND loadtime > ?
ORDER BY loadtime DESC
__END_SQL__

while () {

    $sth->execute($latest);
    my $rows = $sth->fetchall_arrayref;

    # Display $rows

    $latest = $rows->[0][0];

    sleep 60;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can i ask you what is the  function of selectrow_array because i encountered an error at that line.

Comment: @mihoeunn: It combines `prepare`, `execute`, and `fetchrow_array`. Its purpose is to fetch the date/time 30 minutes before the current time, according to the database clock. I'm sorry, I used minute units instead of day units: it is fixed now. Please say what your error message is, and what database system you're using. If it's Oracle then a `SELECT` statement needs a `FROM` clause, and it should read `SELECT sysdate - 0.5/24 FROM DUAL`

Comment: I'm using oracle. A while ago, i've encountered this error on cmd and it is panic: dbd_rebind alen 23> maxlen 0 (incnul 0). Now, trying to run it again it doesnt display anything..i dont know why.